# ModelMapper exception - cannot be cast to org.modelmapper.internal.Mutator

Tags: java, spring, modelmapper

I am getting bellow exception this exception. I am using modelmapper to covert between classes in my project.

The Deal and DealDocument classes are identical. The Deal document class is as bellow:

```
public class DealDocument extends Deal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12390392L;

}
```

WHat do you think could be the issue ? It seems to appear randomly, like it is working ok, but within time system degrades

> 2017-01-31 15:35:45.168 ERROR 21301 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-8]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors: 1) Error
>   mapping com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.model.Deal to
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.model.DealDocument 1 error] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoImpl$MethodAccessor cannot be
>   cast to org.modelmapper.internal.Mutator at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoRegistry.mutatorFor(PropertyInfoRegistry.java:92)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoResolver$3.propertyInfoFor(PropertyInfoResolver.java:75)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoResolver$3.propertyInfoFor(PropertyInfoResolver.java:63)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoSetResolver.resolveProperties(PropertyInfoSetResolver.java:146)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoSetResolver.resolveProperties(PropertyInfoSetResolver.java:136)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoSetResolver.resolveProperties(PropertyInfoSetResolver.java:123)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoSetResolver.resolveMutators(PropertyInfoSetResolver.java:91)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.TypeInfoImpl.getMutators(TypeInfoImpl.java:76)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.ImplicitMappingBuilder.matchDestination(ImplicitMappingBuilder.java:92)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.ImplicitMappingBuilder.build(ImplicitMappingBuilder.java:82)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapStore.getOrCreate(TypeMapStore.java:106)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.TypeMapStore.getOrCreate(TypeMapStore.java:79)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:99)
>   at
>   org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:60)
>   at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:497) at
>   org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:340) at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.config.MarketPlaceModelMapper.map(MarketPlaceModelMapper.java:12)
>   at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.service.impl.DealServiceImpl.saveToES(DealServiceImpl.java:468)
>   at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.service.impl.DealServiceImpl.saveToES(DealServiceImpl.java:461)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor849.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy201.saveToES(Unknown Source) at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.aspect.DealAspect.saveDealtoES(DealAspect.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor848.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:620)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:602)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:47)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.save(Unknown Source) at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.service.impl.DealServiceImpl.saveDeal(DealServiceImpl.java:271)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy201.saveDeal(Unknown Source) at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.controller.DealController.updateDeal(DealController.java:99)
>   at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.controller.DealController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d9a6fb7b.invoke()
>   at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
>   at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.aspect.DealSecurityAspect.dealsSecurity(DealSecurityAspect.java:63)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor511.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:620)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:609)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
>   at
>   com.acme.sugoi.marketplace.controller.DealController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1559db68.updateDeal()
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

*** UPDATE *:**
This is how I have configured the model mapper:
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(false).setFieldMatchingEnabled(true).setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

My Deal class is annotated with @Data (from lombok) , so all attributes are accessible through public methods

Could this be related with [ClassCastException in ModelMapper: EnhancerByModelMapper cannot be cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127438/classcastexception-in-modelmapper-enhancerbymodelmapper-cannot-be-cast) ?

Comment: Please add the `Deal` class structure. It could be a visibility issue.
Try adding this to your instance:

`modelMapper.getConfiguration()
  .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
  .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);`

Comment: this is how I have configured the modelMapper: modelMapper.getConfiguration().setAmbiguityIgnored(false).setFieldMatchingEnabled(true).setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

Comment: My Deal class is annotated with @Data (from lombok) , so all attributes are accessible through public methods

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue might related to https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/204

Currently we had issue when try getting accessor, but getting a mutator.

But I'm not sure how you config Dial class with lombok annotations.
Did Dial's getters/setters had same method name?

If so, I think the issue is what you are looking at, and we plan to fix it in next release.